# Notification clicked from Windows 10 notification bar not working as expected

Tags: javascript, windows-10

I'm working on a page that creates a notification (Notification function of Java-script), that when it appears, do click on it, the focus works as expected.

The problem is when I let go for a while and the notification is stored in the "notification bar" of Windows 10. Clicking on the same notification from that bar, instead of giving focus on the page, opens a new tab with only the domain of the page (eg: www.mywebsite.com instead of www.mywebsite.com/mypage.aspx).

Browser: Chrome.

Tested with Firefox but that browser doesn't create native notifications on Windows 10.

Tested with `parent.focus()` added to the `windows.focus()`, but it doesn't work.

```
notification.onclick = function () {
    window.focus();
    this.close();
}
```

Comment: I have tested this behavior and found that it works fine with Microsoft Edge 17.17134 and this leads me to believe it is Chrome issue. You can submit a bug here for Chromium : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/